# Tinymce image insert not working

Tags: php, tinymce

If i clicks on image insert button i got a pop up, but i am unable to browse the image, browse button is not working can you please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created the uploaded folder?

Comment: create directory 'uploaded' in you document root (where your index.php file is located)... at least that's what we needed to do in work...